# Notification is not showing with workmanager foregroundInfo

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-workmanager, foregroundnotification

I wanted to create a notification with heads up feature . Basically it is a alarm feature. And I wanted to show with notification using `foreground`. Now `workmanager` has the feature to run in foreground using `setForeground` . But it's not showing notifications as I implement it as following :

```
@HiltWorker
class NotificationWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: notification worker called ")
        setForeground(createForegroundInfo())
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun createForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo
    {

        val msg = "messgae "
        val id = 34


        val channelId = "show_reminder"
        val channelName = "Reminder Notification"
        val alarmSound: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
        val vibratePattern = longArrayOf(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500)

        val customView = RemoteViews("packageName", R.layout.alarm_notification)

        customView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, msg.trim())

        val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

       

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            val  channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

...

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext,channelId)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentText(msg.trim())
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(msg.trim()))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_access_alarm_24)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
            .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(customView)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())

        //notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build())


        return ForegroundInfo(id,builder.build())
    }

}
```

When calling notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build()) displays the notification but it won't stay long .How to make heads up notification stay long ?